# Possibility to take away magic from a witch/wizard

Tags: harry-potter

I've seen [Is it possible to lose or gain magic blood](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60227/is-it-possible-to-lose-or-gain-magic-blood) and [Can a wizard or witch lose his magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162984/can-a-wizard-or-witch-lose-his-magic) but they don't seem to really take the question/answer in the direction I've been wondering.

Would it be possible to 'take' away someone's magic? I don't mean (temporarily) 'losing' it by stress or trauma but it being taken away by someone with that specific intent.

For example it's certainly possible to mess around with emotions and the mental state of witches and wizards. The following examples come to mind:

- [Imperius Curse](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/Imperius_Curse) - Take full control of witch/wizard
- Obliviate - Erase memories
- [Amortentia](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/Amortentia) - 'Love potion'
- [Veritaserum](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/Truth_Potion) - 'Truth potion'
- Legilimency - 'Mind reading'
- Pensieve - 'Siphoning memories'

And probably many more I can't think of right now.

Potions are generally 'limited-time' use, while spells can have permanent effects. Has there ever been a case where someones magic is taken away (in the literal sense) by either spell/potion. And if not, do you think it would be possible to do so?

I'd wager Voldemort could possibly figure this out but his solution was to simply Avada Kedavra everyone =/

Comment: Hmm... A part of me wanted to say that spell casting is innate to wizards. But then again, you also have people who had lost some level of autonomy following a traumatic experience that incapacitated them and such (which I think is comparable to the ability to cast spells).

Comment: @Clockwork Exactly. Hence my question. Also (possibly) similar to 'bending' in the Avatar anime. It's possible to take away bending temporarily (ty-lee) or permanently even (aang). Wondering if something alike exists/could exist in the Harry Potter universe.

Comment: Gilderoy Lockhart gives no sign of magic use after his memory charm went wrong but there doesn’t appear to be definite proof that he has.  The Longbottoms were driven mad after extensive use of the Cruciatus curse but again whether they have lost all magical ability, we don’t appear to be told for sure. Tonks does however temporarily lose her metamorphmagus abilities due to her stressful relationship with Lupin

Comment: I don't think OP is talking about trauma based changes. The core of the question is, can someone be "Squibbed"

Comment: @Turbo I was seeing it under the angle that getting "Squibbed" would be akin to my losing my ability to shoot at the range because someone took it (I mean, if they literally took my hands).

Comment: @Clockwork I'm thinking more of the MonStars from Space Jam stealing the basketball playing ability from NBA Players. They're still tall, muscular, etc. . . But they just can't play.

Comment: @Turbo You are right, that's exactly my question

Answer (score 4):

Magic can't be stolen nor taken away.

> “But how are they supposed to have ‘stolen’ magic?” said Ron. “It’s
> mental, if you could steal magic there wouldn’t be any Squibs, would
> there?” “I know,” said Lupin. “Nevertheless, unless you can prove that
> you have at least one close Wizarding relative, you are now deemed to
> have obtained your magical power illegally and must suffer the
> punishment.”
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows. Chapter 11. The Bribe.</sub>

Your ability to cast magic is influenced by your state of mind. Being depressed or bullied can lead to diminished magic and control, as happened to Tonks, Ariana or Merope.

However, it isn't a loss of magic nor would it be permanent. The magic is still there, but they merely don't want to use it or lack the concentration to do so.

> Merope stopped using magic. I do not think that she wanted to be a witch any longer. Of course, it is also possible that her unrequited love and the attendant despair sapped her of her powers; that can happen. In any case, as you are about to see, Merope refused to raise her wand even to save her own life.”
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince. Chapter 13. The Secret Riddle.</sub>